# Script not executing in Thymeleaf template, getting 'Error OK'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

Hi I am using Thymeleaf and spring boot, view is displayed but the script tag is not executing it gives me ERROR OK on console, I am new to this, can some one help

This is my Thymeleaf template (HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<!-- jQuery Cdn import -->
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
    <header>Report Scheduling</header>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>  
    <p th:text="${queryData}"></p>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        console.log("Script Executed");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("analyticsdashboard/neoApi")
public class RSChartsController {
    @Autowired
    CatalogService catalogService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RSChartsController.class);
    
    
    @GetMapping("/RSChartsController")
    public String RSChartsController(Model model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws SQLException
    {
        Object queryData =catalogService.reportChartDetails();

        model.addAttribute("queryData",queryData);
        return "RSChartsTemplate";
    }
}
```

Every time i hit "RSChartsController" api from frontend the html content shows but script is not executing, I am not understanding what mistake I am doing

showing me following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOGIC.png)

& preview
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H30bG.png)

can somebody help me in understanding why my script is not executing, it should show me output in console as "Script Executed"

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! Please, edit your question to include the code from the screenshot. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12320578)

Comment: Anyone got the answer for this problem.I am also facing the same issue.